# Dynamic element name attributes with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays, post

My HTML structure is something like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="array[a][b][0][foo]" />
  <input type="text" name="array[a][b][0][bar]" />
  <select name="array[0][a][b][baz]>...</select>
</div>
```

Where the element values are submitted through POST and processed by PHP.
The `select` element has a `change` event attached, that [clones](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the parent `div` and appends it below.

When the `div` is cloned the elements' names are still the same and the values would overwrite each other, I don't want this to happen.
All `array[a][b]` elements are of type array, therefore I can't simply use `array[a][b][]` (the foo/bar/baz values would no longer be grouped).

The best way around this is to change the names when they're cloned? This means that the indexes need to be incremented. I can't use a simple `el.name.replace(N, N + 1)` here, because it's the possible the name has multiple occurrences of N.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I read your description a few times and I'm still at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

You can name a class to the parent `<div>` and when you clone, you do it with that class name.

```
<div class="a">
  <input type="text" name="array[a][b][0][foo]" />
  <input type="text" name="array[a][b][0][bar]" />
  <select name="array[0][a][b][baz]>...</select>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <input type="text" name="array[a][b][1][foo]" />
  <input type="text" name="array[a][b][1][bar]" />
  <select name="array[1][a][b][baz]>...</select>
</div>
```

Then, in your javascript you can do:

```
var n = $('.a').length;
```

This, using jquery, returns `2`, that you can use with the replace function.